# Can I replace Kohler 1044458 "water saving(?)" flapper with something better, e.g. 1039861 or 1068622?

Tags: toilet

My Kohler toilet tank has this part in it:

Kohler 1044458 Flush Valve Kit

[image]

The flapper is elevated from the bottom of the tank, preventing the tank from flushing all the way. I imagine this was somebody's brilliant idea to save water, but it's actually kind of stupid because the toilet constantly gets clogged and has to be flushed multiple times to fully "clear out."

Can I safely replace this with a different part, such as one of these?

Kohler 1039861
[image]

Kohler 1068622
[image]

If not, what would be the correct part to use if I want the toilet tank to flush all the way down, providing a stronger flush?

Comment: That's not so unreasonable, since the toilet isn't getting clogged on urine, so you're only really having to multi-flush on big projects with paperwork.  The rest of the time you're saving water.  They also make 2-tier handles where you can choose a little flush or a lot.